# javascript regex with [x|y|z|xy|yz]

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex:

```
\[[^\[\]]*\]\s*[<>|<=|>=|=|>|<]\s*'?"?\w*'?"?
```

this basically just parse a equation like:

```
[household_roster_relationships_topersona_nameadditionalpersono] = "1"
```

it works good, with

```
'=','>','<'.
```

but when the equation has

```
'<=','>=','<>'.
```

the parse stop at first character of

```
'<=','>=','<>'.
```

I have created a demo [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hM29pd/2)

How can I correct regex so it will work in this situation?

Comment: You should learn about character class: `[<>|<=|>=|=|>|<]` == `[=><|]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the character class with a grouping construct.

Use

```
\[[^[\]]*]\s*(?:<>|[<>]=|[=><])\s*['"]?\w*['"]?
             ^^^              ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/43K97Y/1). The `(?:<>|[<>]=|[=><])` *non-capturing* group (only used for grouping subpatterns) matches either `<>`, `<=`, `>=`, `=`, `>` or `<`.

Note I reduced some alternative branches to make the pattern a bit more compact. Also, I think you just want to match either `'` or `"` at the end, so, a mere `['"]?` (1 or 0 `'` or `"`) should be enough.

Also, you do not need to escape a `[` inside a character class (`[[]` matches a single `[`) and you do not need to escape `]` outside a character class, it matches a literal `]` symbol.

Comment: Hi, that works good. with the example in the demo. I have another example that break the regex.
[diagnostic_procedures_performed] = 'UNDEFINED_CODE' and [other_procedure_date]  > "01-01-1901"

how would I fix too?

Comment: Replace `\w*` with `[\w-]*` (0+ word or `-`  symbols) or with `[^"']*` (0+ chars other than `'` and `"`). The latter may be more generic.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your char class for an alternation:

```
\[[^\[\]]*\]\s*(<>|<=|>=|=|>|<)\s*'?"?\w*'?"?
               ^              ^
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/DFhRS9/1)

Comment: Probably make it a non-capturing group as well!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir one can, but this will not change the match

Comment: It will enhance the performance though! OP may learn something!

Comment: See the section **Non-Capturing Groups** [**here**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). It says _you can optimize ..._!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir it doesn't says if it's about speed opti or data volume opti, I'll run some tests

Comment: Just log the return of the match and you'll understand!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I *know* the difference in the returned data, I have no clue about performance difference

Comment: In this example the performance is pretty much the same because there is only one group of at most 2 characters. But it's not a good practice to use capturing groups if they won't be used. That's why I said OP could learn something (to use in future regular expressions)!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `()` instead of `[]` for multiple word character class selection ...[see updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/hM29pd/3)